# How to connect oracle database with python pypyodbc

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, pypyodbc

I am trying to connect an oracle database from my python code using `pypyodbc`:

```
conn_string = "driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; server='example.oneco.com:1521'; database='tabto'; uid='myuid'; pwd='mypwd'"
conn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_string)
```

I got error message:

> Error: (u'HY000', u'[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol
>   adapter error\n')

Following is the connection string found in my `tnsnames.ora` file. Please tell me what is the right way to use `pypyodbc`.

```
tabto, tabto.world, tabto.oracleoutsourcing.com, tabto.oneco.com =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = example.oneco.com)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = tabto_dcu)
    )
  )
```

Comment: The key is to link python code to tnsname.ora by define dbq parameter. So change the code to the following worked. ```conn_string = "driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; dbq='tabto'; uid='myuid'; pwd='mypwd'"
conn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_string)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is link python code to tnsname.ora by defining `dbq` parameter. So change the code to the following worked.

```
conn_string = "driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; dbq='tabto'; uid='myuid'; pwd='mypwd'"
conn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_string)
```

Comment: I just want to clarify for future references, as I got confused about this. But the parameter for dbq can be any of the tns names specified. So dbq='tabto.oneco.com' or dbq='tabto.world' would work also.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=example.oneco.com:1521;DATABASE=tabto;UID=youruid;PWD=password')
```

try it without quotes(') of your code in the middle...

check too pyodbc wiki: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows